# Question about the details in meaning between gerund and to-infinite

Tags: gerunds, gerund-vs-infinitive

Consider the following multiple-choice question:

> The supervisors were asked ______ tasks to new employees so that they could be trained to do them properly.
>
> A. Delegate - *infinitive*
> B. To delegate - *To + infinitive*
> C. delegating - *gerund*
> D. delegation - *noun*

I was wondering after improvising some structures in the sentence like below.

Question 1 - What if there is a choice E: 'delegating for'?  Would this be a valid answer?

> The supervisors were asked for delegating tasks to new employees so that they could be trained to do them properly.

Question 2 - Could 'for' be a substitute for 'to'? If so, will it have the same meaning?

> The supervisors were asked delegating tasks ***for*** new employees so that they could be trained to do them properly.

Could this make sense too? Under the premise that delegating tasks is the noun to have meaning itself.

Comment: The short answer is *no*, you must use the infinitive (*to delegate*) in sentences structured like your example. You could not use *for* like that. As to why... I'll leave that to my better informed colleagues here on EL&U. You may also be interested in our sister site for people trying to learn English as a second language: [ELL.se].

Comment: Thank you Dan, i will wait for other answers and i will make a use of your suggested website too.

Comment: I don't understand that **B, To delegate - supine**. To quote Wikipedia, [In grammar a supine is a form of verbal noun used in some languages.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supine) Those languages apparently include Latin, but not English.

Comment: Dear Fumble Fingers, i edited my post. Thank you for the correction

Comment: @FumbleFingers, The OP's text is using 'supine' to describe the group *'to* *delegate'* .  (and it is a verbal noun)  and 'infinitive' to describe the basic verb form.

Comment: @Hugh, What are your thoughts on my answer? I see Dan addressed it simply doesn't make sense but is it not making sense because of flow in meaning or grammar structure?

Comment: "The supervisors were asked **to delegate** tasks to new employees" is the only correct choice,  Dan Bron calls this the infinitive: your text calls it "supine" or else "to + infinitive" and Fumble fingers has shown that this nomenclature is unfamiliar. We all agree which answer is correct. We are not used to your wording.

Comment: As for your **Question1** This is the first problem:  To delegate a task is to pass it on to someone else, (or) ..to transfer it to another workman.  In your example  the supervisors were asked to do this. *To_ask_some_one_to* do something is a compound verb.

Comment: The second problem is this:  "The delegates were *asked* *for* something" would have a completely different meaning. and that is followed by a noun or a verbal noun; but it cannot be made to work here with the words in your example.

Comment: @Hugh, You have been so much helpful. I must stick to the meaning of the complete sentence itself instead of forming the correct structure.

Comment: I would delete "spine/supine" in the headline. It is totally confusing. In English there does not exist a supine. It is a minor verb form in Latin in  some older expressions.

Comment: Gerund and to-infinitive, see the very detailed website http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/

Answer (score 1):

1. In school, we were specifically taught to use to-infinitives in place of for-doing verbs. So "to delegate" would be preferred to "for delegating". Not only is it neater to read, it is the correct usage.
2. "asked delegating" is again wrong. Replacing it with "to delegate", it becomes:

"The supervisors were asked to delegate tasks for new employees so that they could be trained to do them properly."

Now we can analyse it. Delegating a task *to* a person means telling them to do that task. Delegating a task *for* a person means doing the delegation for that person so he/she doesn't have to. So no, it won't work as a substitute. And it doesn't have the same meaning, as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that is sure is that the construction verb + to-infinitive is the most frequent and normal construction.
Only a small group of verbs use the bare infinitive. Some verbs are followed  by a gerund, and these verbs must be learnt from grammars. Only in rare cases one can give a reason why a gerund is preferred to a to-infinitive.

In any case, you can't chose any construction you like. If uncertain you have to consult the dictionary to see how the verb is constructed.